# Convert roman numeral to integer

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The roman numeral to integer converter I am following:

https://www.selftaughtjs.com/algorithm-sundays-converting-roman-numerals/

My attempt at converting the Javascript function to Java:

```
public class RomanToDecimal {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int result = 0;
    int[] decimal = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
    String[] roman = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

    // Test string, the number 895
    String test = "DCCCXCV";

    for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length; i++ ) {
        while (test.indexOf(roman[i]) == 0) {
            result += decimal[i];
            test = test.replace(roman[i], "");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

The output is **`615`**, which is incorrect.

Please help me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `test = test.replace(roman[i], "");` replaces all occurrences of "C" with "", so after you find the first "C" and add 100 to the total, you eliminate all the remaining "C"s, and never count them. Therefore you actually compute the value of `"DCXV"`, which is `615`.

You should only replace the occurrence of `roman[i]` whose start index 0, which you can achieve by replacing:

```
test = test.replace(roman[i], "");
```

with:

```
test = test.substring(roman[i].length()); // this will remove the first 1 or 2 characters
                                          // of test, depending on the length of roman[i]
```

The following:

```
int result = 0;
int[] decimal = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
String[] roman = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

// Test string, the number 895
String test = "DCCCXCV";

for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length; i++ ) {
    while (test.indexOf(roman[i]) == 0) {
        result += decimal[i];
        test = test.substring(roman[i].length());
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

prints:

```
895
```

Answer (score 1):

`test = test.replace(roman[i], "");`

This will replace every occurrence. Instead, you should only truncate off the occurrence at the beginning of the string (position 0).

Try using `substring` instead of replace, and pass as an argument the length of `roman[i]`

Answer (score 0):

def value(r):
if (r == 'I'):
return 1
if (r == 'V'):
return 5
if (r == 'X'):
return 10
if (r == 'L'):
return 50
if (r == 'C'):
return 100
if (r == 'D'):
return 500
if (r == 'M'):
return 1000
return -1

def romanToDecimal(str):
res = 0
i = 0

```
while (i < len(str)):

    # Getting value of symbol s[i]
    s1 = value(str[i])

    if (i + 1 < len(str)):

        # Getting value of symbol s[i + 1]
        s2 = value(str[i + 1])

        # Comparing both values
        if (s1 >= s2):

            # Value of current symbol is greater
            # or equal to the next symbol
            res = res + s1
            i = i + 1
        else:

            # Value of current symbol is greater
            # or equal to the next symbol
            res = res + s2 - s1
            i = i + 2
    else:
        res = res + s1
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: Why are you using Python code to answer a Java question?
Also, use backticks to wrap your whole code.
Make sure to give a small explanation, not just a huge code block.