# How do you concat two hashmap values?

Tags: java

My professor gave us this project where you need to convert the roman numeral from User Input into text form of the number. It's a bit overwhelming for me cause I'm still a beginner in Java.

This is the hashmap I made (Ik It's not the best and not much logic going on) and I'm wondering how do you concat the hashmap value if the user inputs like 'DVIII' which the 'D' has value of "Five Hundred" and the 'VIII' has value of "Eight" then print them out as
DVIII = Five Hundred Eight

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
         
HashMap<String, String> Roman = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Roman.put("I","One");
        Roman.put("II","Two");
        Roman.put("III","Three");
        Roman.put("IV","Four");
        Roman.put("V","Five");
        Roman.put("VI","Six");
        Roman.put("VII","Seven");
        Roman.put("VIII","Eight");
        Roman.put("IX","Nine");
        Roman.put("X","Ten");
        Roman.put("XI","Eleven");
        Roman.put("XII","Twelve");
        Roman.put("XIII","Thirteen");
        Roman.put("XIV","Fourteen");
        Roman.put("XV","Fifteen");
        Roman.put("XVI","Sixteen");
        Roman.put("XVII","Seventeen");
        Roman.put("XVIII","Eighteen");
        Roman.put("XIX","Nineteen");
        Roman.put("XX","Twenty");
        Roman.put("XXX","Thirty");
        Roman.put("XL","Fourty");
        Roman.put("L","Fifty");
        Roman.put("LX","Sixty");
        Roman.put("LXX","Seventy");
        Roman.put("LXXX","Eighty");
        Roman.put("XC","Ninety");
        Roman.put("C","One Hundred");
        Roman.put("CC","Two Hundred");
        Roman.put("CCC","Three Hundred");
        Roman.put("CD","Four Hundred");
        Roman.put("D","Five Hundred");
        Roman.put("DC","Six Hundred");
        Roman.put("DCC","Seven Hundred");
        Roman.put("DCCC","Eight Hundred");
        Roman.put("CM","Nine Hundred");
        Roman.put("M","One Thousand");
        Roman.put("MM","Two Thousand");
        Roman.put("MMM","Three Thousand");
        Roman.put("MMMM","Four Thousand");
        
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter a Roman Numeral: ");
        String RomanNumeral = Input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("\n The equivalent of the Roman numeral "+RomanNumeral+" is " + Roman.get(RomanNumeral));
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this to convert to integer value [Convert roman numeral to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647368/convert-roman-numeral-to-integer) Then conversion of integer to words is easy if you split the thousands, hundreds, tens, ones place digits

Comment: I think it is better to convert user input to arabic number system first and only then convert those into text.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to convert the roman number to a decimal number (here is an example code for that)
[convert roman-numeral to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647368/convert-roman-numeral-to-integer)
and thereafter convert that number to a word (and here is example code for that)
[convert number to word](https://gist.github.com/madan712/be79a395424bf773be87)

You could also do it like this but I find this way really bad since it wastes memory by making a huuuuuge hashmap and its a bunch of uneccesary code and duplication

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        //all numbers one to nine
        HashMap<String, String> RomanFirstDigit = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //all numbers ten to twenty
        HashMap<String, String> RomanToTwenty = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //twenty, thirty, forty etc
        HashMap<String, String> RomanSecondDigit = new HashMap<String, String>();

        RomanFirstDigit.put("I","One");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("II","Two");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("III","Three");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("IV","Four");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("V","Five");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("VI","Six");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("VII","Seven");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("VIII","Eight");
        RomanFirstDigit.put("IX","Nine");

        RomanToTwenty.put("X","Ten");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XI","Eleven");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XII","Twelve");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XIII","Thirteen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XIV","Fourteen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XV","Fifteen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XVI","Sixteen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XVII","Seventeen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XVIII","Eighteen");
        RomanToTwenty.put("XIX","Nineteen");

        RomanSecondDigit.put("XX","Twenty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("XXX","Thirty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("XL","Fourty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("L","Fifty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("LX","Sixty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("LXX","Seventy");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("LXXX","Eighty");
        RomanSecondDigit.put("XC","Ninety");

        //make a hashmap with all numbers between one and hundred
        HashMap<String, String> RomanOneToHundred = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        RomanOneToHundred.putAll(RomanFirstDigit);
        RomanOneToHundred.putAll(RomanSecondDigit);
        RomanOneToHundred.putAll(RomanToTwenty);

        //loop over the hashmap with twenty, thirty etc with the one that has one to nine
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entryFirst : RomanSecondDigit.entrySet()){
            for (Map.Entry<String,String> entrySecond : RomanFirstDigit.entrySet()){
                RomanOneToHundred.put(entryFirst.getKey() + entrySecond.getKey(),
                    entryFirst.getValue() + " " + entrySecond.getValue());
            }

        }

        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter a Roman Numeral: ");
        String RomanNumeral = Input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n The equivalent of the Roman numeral "+RomanNumeral+" is " + RomanOneToHundred
            .get(RomanNumeral));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK first of all, your question can be solved with an algorithm, as [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15479032/emilmalmsten) said, I don't think its feasible to define static values to parse a roman numerical. For example in your code you do not specify the length of a string for it to be considered a valid number, and can't distinguish the difference between different arrangements of symbols.

Example:

> If you are converting a single characterat a time: `DIV` would translate to `[500, 1, 5]`.

*Therefore*; you will need to specify some rules - In other words you will need **an algorithm**.

So, You have one of two options:

1. Implement the algorithm yourself, which can be quite tricky for a beginner.

> This option needs a different question, because it's unrelated to map concating question, you can ask/search on this site, about implementing a `roman numerical converter` or something in that context.

2. Use a library that has this functionality, with a small search I found [this one](https://frequal.com/RomanNumerals/index.html)